# How to make a request on a subgraph?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, subgraph

I try to do some requests like the following one:

```
MATCH path = (f1:Frag)-[r1:I]->(f2:Frag)-[r2:I]->(f3:Frag)-[r3:I]->
 (f4:Frag)-[r4:I]->(f5:Frag)-[r5:I]->(f6:Frag)
 WHERE (r1.at2 <> r2.at1 AND r2.at2 <> r3.at1 AND r3.at2 <> r4.at1
  AND r4.at2 <> r5.at1) AND (not((f1)-[:E]-(f3)) AND not((f1)-[:E]-(f4))
  AND not((f1)-[:E]-(f5)) AND not((f1)-[:E]-(f6)) AND not((f2)-[:E]-(f4))
  AND not((f2)-[:E]-(f5)) AND not((f2)-[:E]-(f6)) AND not((f3)-[:E]-(f5))
  AND not((f3)-[:E]-(f6)) AND not((f4)-[:E]-(f6)))
RETURN path LIMIT 10
```

But when I want to restrict my request to some relationships like:

```
MATCH path = (f1:Frag)-[r1:I]->(f2:Frag)-[r2:I]->(f3:Frag)-[r3:I]->
 (f4:Frag)-[r4:I]->(f5:Frag)-[r5:I]->(f6:Frag)
 WHERE (r1.at2 <> r2.at1 AND r2.at2 <> r3.at1 AND r3.at2 <> r4.at1
  AND r4.at2 <> r5.at1) AND (not((f1)-[:E]-(f3)) AND not((f1)-[:E]-(f4))
  AND not((f1)-[:E]-(f5)) AND not((f1)-[:E]-(f6)) AND not((f2)-[:E]-(f4))
  AND not((f2)-[:E]-(f5)) AND not((f2)-[:E]-(f6)) AND not((f3)-[:E]-(f5))
  AND not((f3)-[:E]-(f6)) AND not((f4)-[:E]-(f6)))
  AND ALL(r in relationships(path) WHERE r.niv <20)
RETURN path LIMIT 10
```

It takes much more time to find some solutions than on all the relationships, because it uses all the relationships.

Is is possible to restrict the request to a subgraph ?

Answer (score 1):

The following much-simplified form of your query should be logically equivalent to yours (if an `I` relationship from a `Frag` node always ends at a `Frag` node), and returns the ordered relationships and nodes of your desired paths. (You can actually just return `rs`, since a relationship contains references to its start and end nodes). The [profile](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) of this query is also a lot simpler than the one for yours, so this query *may* be faster.

```
MATCH p = (:Frag)-[:I*5]->(:Frag)
WITH RELATIONSHIPS(p) AS rs, NODES(p) AS ns
WHERE
  ALL(i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(rs)-2) WHERE rs[i].at2 <> rs[i+1].at1) AND
  ALL(j IN ns[0..-2] WHERE ALL(k IN ns[2..] WHERE NOT (j)-[:E]-(k))) AND
  ALL(r in rs WHERE r.niv < 20)
RETURN *
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This request is actually simpler but it is still slow. Even with  
   MATCH p = (:Frag)-[:I*5]->(:Frag)
   WITH RELATIONSHIPS(p) AS rs, NODES(p) AS ns
   WHERE
   ALL(r in rs WHERE r.niv < 20)
   RETURN rs
   LIMIT 10   it is slow because the subgraph with relationships having niv < 20 is not chosen. Is there a way to to that ?

Comment: Yes, move that particular part into a WHERE clause immediately following the MATCH: `MATCH ... WHERE ALL(r in relationships(p) WHERE r.niv < 20) WITH ...`